# Extracting SSt data from netCDF4 using SPYDER

Tags: python, netcdf4

I am a beginner in using net CDF data and Spyder as well.
I made a `DataFrame` to extract SST data, but I got stuck there.
I think I have to define the data range.

My variables are: `sst`, `long`, and `lat`.
I'd appreciate your help

I tried this code:

```
temp = data.variables['sst']

df = pd.DataFrame(0, columns = ['Temperature'], index = lon)

df_2 = pd.DataFrame(0, columns = ['Temperature'], index = lat)

print(data.dimensions)

data.variables['lon']
```

Comment: What are `data`, `lon` and `lat` and where do you get them from? What result do you get from the code above and what did you want to get?

Comment: its sea water temperature data i downloaded from ocean color site, it is a data of July 2023, and i want to get a csv file for the temperature